# ng-model is not working with ng-value in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, input, angularjs-1.6

**Below is my View page**

```
<form name="form">
     <label>Name</label>
     <input name="name" type="text" ng-model='user.name' ng-value='emp.name' required />
     <span ng-show="form.name.$touched && form.name.$invalid">Name is required</span>
     <button ng-disabled="form.name.$touched && form.name.$invalid" ng-click='formUpdate()'>Update</button>
</form>
```

**This is my controller**

```
$scope.formUpdate = function() {
  $scope.status = false;
  $http({
  method : 'POST',
  url : 'model/update.php',
  data :   $scope.user ,
  headers : {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}          

  }).then(function mySuccess(response) {
    $scope.update = response.data;
    console.log(response.data); 
   }, function myError(response) {
    $scope.update = response.statusText;

   }); 
};
```

When I am using  data: `$scope.user` in my HTTP call I am getting blank values on console but if I used  data: `$scope.emp`, then I never get updated values of input fields rather getting old values of input fields.

Comment: What is the purpose if ths `ng-value` what is the expected result?

Comment: i am implementing update logic with the help of form , ng-value lifts old values from table , and if user wants to update its field value , then new values should be reflected in DB

Comment: This is what I guessed, see [**my answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42952719/4927984).

Answer (score 2):

[`ng-value`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngValue) binds the given expression to the value of the element.

As I understand your question, you are trying to initialize the input value to `emp.name`.

You should change your input to:

```
<input type="text" ng-model='user.name' ng-init='user.name = emp.name' required />
```

[`ng-init` docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit)

Comment: Thanks Mistalis,  given solution doesnot working for me

Comment: @wasimbeg Could you explain what "*is not working*"? Can't help you more with no more precision...

Answer (score 0):

try this code;

```
$scope.formUpdate = function(){
  $scope.status = false;
  $scope.$applyAsync();

  $http({
  method : 'POST',
  url : 'model/update.php',
  data :   $scope.user ,
  headers : {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}          

  }).then(function mySuccess(response) {
    $scope.update = response.data;
    $scope.$applyAsync();
    console.log(response.data); 
   }, function myError(response) {
    $scope.update = response.statusText;  
    $scope.$applyAsync();
   }); 

  };
```